# Factor of a joint density into product of functions

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose a joint density $f_{(X,Y)}(x,y) $ factors :

$$ f_{(X,Y)}(x,y) = g(x) h(y) $$

Is there a way to find $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y) $

Can we just say that since $f_{(X,Y)}(x,y) = f_X(x) f_Y(y) $, then

$$ f_X(x) = \frac{ g(x) h(y)}{f_Y(y) } $$

and similarly for the other density ?

Comment: If both $g$ and $h$ are non-negative, then $f_X(x)=(\int_\mathbb{R} g(x)\,\mathrm dx)^{-1} g(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

The equality: $$f_{X,Y}\left(x,y\right)=g\left(x\right)h\left(y\right)$$
allows the conclusion that there are constants $a,b$ with $ab=1$
and such that: $$f_{X}\left(x\right)=ag\left(x\right)\text{ and }f_{Y}\left(y\right)=bh\left(y\right)$$
So to be found are these constants on base of the data: $$a\int g\left(x\right)dx=1=b\int h\left(y\right)dx$$
We allready have equality $ab=1$ so it is enough to find one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes you can. The equality follows only after you have realized that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $f(x,y)=g(x)\>h(y)$ and that $f(x,y)>0$ in some domain $\Omega\subset{\mathbb R}^2$. Then
$$f_x(x,y)=g'(x)\>h(y)={g'(x)\over g(x)} f(x,y)$$
in $\Omega$. It follows that
$${f_x(x,y)\over f(x,y)}={g'(x)\over g(x)}\tag{1}$$
depends only on $x$ (which can also serve as test whether our basic assumption is indeed fulfilled). On the other hand the LHS of $(1)$ is given to us, so that we now have a simple differential equation for $g$. When $g$ has been found we obtain $h$ in the form $h(y)={f(x,y)\over g(x)}$.